# HTML - Copy content of tab into another tab and modify ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website where I'm using jqwidgets Tab functionality.

Essentially I have a single tab with lots of elements (Form type data) on it along with associated java script that works on the elements (Sliders, Text boxes, etc..).  The user will have the option to "add a new tab" up to about 6 or so.  When the user clicks this I need to basically create a duplicate form in the new tab.

When the user selects "SUBMIT" at the end I need to be able to pull the form data from all of my tabs and execute appropriately.

My original tab html data is mostly static except for a few lookups.  I have lots of javascript working on these elements.
My question is what is the best approach to create a duplicate form/content into the new tabs.  My guess is that I would need to copy all of the original tab's elements onto the new tab...But I need the ID's to be unique so that my js can work on them.   I was looking at clone but struggling and not sure if this is the right approach.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

## Tab functionality

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtabs/index.htm?%28arctic%29#demos/jqxtabs/closebuttons.htm

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: No code for the copy pieces.  I'm looking for a general approach as resolution for this question.  Essentially I start with a single TAB with an "Add New". I have a form with about 20 unique elements on this tab and about a thousand lines of java script code that works on these elements.   I have a single page app using ajax.   When user selects the "Add new Server" I need all the content in the original TAB to show up in the new TAB. (And I need the js functionality to work).  So my thoughts are that I need unique ID's for the new tabs and my JS needs to be able to support both/multiple tabs.

Comment: Are the tabs contained inside a div?

Comment: yes, each tab is it's own DIV

Comment: Looks like this will do what I need it to do for the HTML...But not sure about approach for copying all the JS so that it works on the new elements.     http://tristandenyer.com/using-jquery-to-duplicate-a-section-of-a-form-maintaining-accessibility/

Comment: yeah but are the those divs enclosed in a parent div?